# JavaScript Multiplier Script

Tags: javascript

So I've very recently dived into JS and i'm not quite understanding the Logical steps here i'm assuming.

My question is, So let's say i wanted to have a multiplier that can be bought to increase food income by 2x, how would i cap it from being purchased again?

```
'
var gameData = {
gold: 0,
goldPerClick: 1,
goldPerClickCost: 10,
food: 0,
foodPerClick: 2,
foodUpgradeCost: 10,
```

}

```
  function x2() {
    if (gameData.foodPerClick >=2) {
      gameData.foodPerClick *= 2
    } else (gameData.foodPerClick ????)
    applied = "Used";
    document.getElementById("applied").innerHTML = applied
  }'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `gameData` object keep a boolean.

```
var gameData = {
   //other attributes
   
   isxTwoApplied: false
}
```

Then when executing the `x2()` check if `isxTwoApplied === false`and change this to `true`.

```
function x2() {
    if (!gameData.isxTwoApplied) {
       if (gameData.foodPerClick >=2) {
          gameData.foodPerClick *= 2
          gameData.isxTwoApplied = true
       } else

    //rest of the code
  }'
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry to be a complete newbie, still trying to understand the logical approaches and syntax properly.

Comment: No worries.. :)